# How to use Filefield to upload a file to shrarepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, content-type

I am rendering the fields of a selected content type (spcontrolmode=new).
The name field is rendered as a FileField where i can select a local file.

How to upload this local file to sharepoint, using this FileField?

i tried to parse it to a FileUpload control, but its impossible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the file upload control for this.

What was your problem with the file upload control? Purhaps you could post some of your code.

**EDIT**

Here is a description of how to do it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454491.aspx

Comment: That;s the point, When i render the name field of a document using spcontrolmode=new, it automatically creates a microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.filefield and not a fileupload.